# How to display status for On, Off, Faulty

Tags: tables, labels, data-tables, status

I have a table which shows whether devices are `ON` or `OFF`.
Currently, it looks like this

| Status | Name | Some other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | DeviceA |  |
|  | DeviceB |  |
|  | DeviceC |  |

There is a new requirement, which is to show devices which are `FAULTY`.
A faulty device can be `ON` or `OFF`.

The most straightforward solution would be to put the `FAULTY` label next to the ON/OFF icon, like so

| Status | Name | Some other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | DeviceA |  |
| `FAULTY` | DeviceB |  |
| `FAULTY` | DeviceC |  |

However, I'm concerned about users confusing the  for `FAULTY`

Some possible alternatives I've considered:

- Spell out `ON` `OFF` instead of using
- Make `FAULTY` its own column, instead of sharing a column with ``` ON``OFF ```
- Find an appropriate icon for `FAULTY` & possibly `HEALTHY`

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 6):

As it is correlated with the function status: ON / OFF, it's a good choice to show both statuses close to each other as they both indicate the need for action.

But other than that, you should asses what kind of devices you are running, what the damage is when they run with faults or when they stop, how quick action is needed in order to signal, notify responsible people and make sure corrective measures are taken when needed.

[image]

Comment: I would do similar myself, but I would avoid having the "without faults" icon/label. It's just distracting. Just show an icon/label for "with faults" if there are any.

Comment: Agreed. Also, orange is actually not a great colour for off because it suggests an effort or warning itself. Should use grey for off and reserve orange for the faulty icon.

Comment: Agreed on not showing without faults. Sorry for the orange confusion ... Figma Jam doesn't offer red color, just orange :)) should have specified.